# Can't set max height for sub-menu collapsible item

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to make some menu with some sub-menu (with Ant Design), I want it have a limit height, if the content in that sub-menu is longer max-height, that sub-menu can be scroll. I tried style it with `max-height` an `overflow-y: scroll` but it's not work. the frist sub-menu is override the other sub-menu. What is wrong? Thanks!

This is [my reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/submenu-height-problem-54few?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot "px" in your "max-height:240" style